# Testing OAuth with Capybara/Rspec for Facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a test for Facebook integration. When I run rspec, I get the following error

```
 Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign in with Facebook" }
 NoMethodError:
 undefined method `provider' for #<Hash:0x007fbe98511798>
 # ./app/models/user.rb:55:in `from_omniauth'
```

My OAuth mock contains

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = {
  'uid'       => "999999",
  'provider'  => "facebook",
  'extra'     => {
    'user_hash' => {
      'email'   => 'test@gmail.com',
      'first_name'  => 'First',
      'last_name'   => 'Last',
      'gender'  => 'Male'
    }
  },
  'credentials' => {
    'token' => "token1234qwert"
  }
}
```

The exact place it apparently breaks is

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where("fb_provider = ? and fb_uid = ?", auth.provider, auth.uid.to_s).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
```

But when I do a `puts auth.to_yaml` as the first line in `from_omniauth(auth)` it shows `provider: facebook` along with everything else I included in my mock auth. I'm lost at this point. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be this:

```
where("fb_provider = ? and fb_uid = ?", auth['provider'], auth['uid'].to_s ...
```

This is because `auth` in this instance is a `Hash` object and `Hash` objects do not respond to methods by the same name as their keys. Instead, you should just use the `Hash#[]` method -- as I've demonstrated -- to access the value for those keys.